# git extensions single file history only diffs

Tags: git, git-extensions

The command

```
gitk filename
```

let's you see all commits in which the file was changed.

Is this possible for git extensions?
The single file history view does this - unfortunately it shows you the full history with all the commits, not just the ones which effectively changed the file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the setting by comparing my Git Extension config with one of my colleague:

```
<key>
    <string>fullhistoryinfilehistory</string>
</key>
<value>
    <string>true</string>
</value>
```

I set the value to false, now it's working as intended. Can't find the GUI-equivalent setting in Git Extension though...

Edit: Found it! Not in the settings but in the context menu in the file history -> Full history: [image: enable/disable full history in file history view]

Comment: Great find.  IMO, not a great use of the context menu, considering it operates on the whole window, and not just a single file.

Comment: I don't see that context menu.  

On windows, settings file is C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\GitExtensions\GitExtensions\GitExtensions.settings

Comment: It's only visible in the File History windows of a file. Not in the main view. Still there for me with newest version 2.5.